# Migrating the database from Oracle to MySQL What Changes has to be done in hibernate

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Currently in our spring boot application bwe are using ojdbc jar and hibernate jars.We are planning to migrate to MySQL.
Are MySQL jars compatible with hibernate jars, also are there any drastic changes that one will have to do the dao layer when the migration is done(eg:the id generation strategies, @embedded,composite keys)

In application.properties we will have to change the connection strings.
But what else has to be taken care of

Comment: you need to add proper jdbc driver for your database, checking `start.spring.io` i can see there is driver `runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'`, you most certainly need to replace this. and also your configuration file may have to specify which driver class is supposed to be used.

Comment: Unless you're using many native queries (either via @Query or JdbcTemplate), this should be a relatively smooth process. As for the necessary jars, if you're using Maven, then it's just a matter of adding the right dependencies.

Comment: Don't forget to check if there's anything Oracle specific being used (triggers, packages, materialized views, etc).

Comment: dsp_user
  we are using @Query in our app, is there any changes that i have to take care of.

Comment: @dsp_user we are using Query in our app, What changes are required in these scenarios.

Comment: @Ashwini Pai, are you using Query with nativeQuery=true set? If not, then you shouldn't worry, otherwise you might need to reexamine your queries, but it's impossible for me to say whether any adjustments will be necessary without actually seeing those queries.